# Get Post's first image using Short-code

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

i'm trying to get post's first image(LINK) , Currently i'm using [Shorcodes Ultimade](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/) plugin for it so far i'm able to get post's content using the following shortcode on my static homepage page

```
[su_post field="post_content" default="" before="" after="" post_id="68" filter=""]
```

but the above shortcode is returning the whole content (Images + Post's text)

i checked the documentation and they don't seem to have any built in solution for getting only image from a post, Any one know how can i get only the image or can i filter out only image from returned data?

Comment: You could theoretically [run a `preg_match` on the post content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php) and search for the image-tag but that is no good idea. Why not use the featured image function of WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite  a simple shortcode to retrieve only post images:

```
add_shortcode( "postImages", "stack_309224_attachhment" );

function stack_309224_attachhment($atts){
extract(shortcode_atts( array(
  'id'      => 1, // default id of the post
  "max"   =>4 ,// default max number of images to display
  "featured"=>"false" // if to retrieve the post featured image or not, default false
),  $atts ));

ob_start();
if($atts['featured']=="true"){ // display only the featured image
  ?>
  <figure><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( (int)$atts['id']) )[0]?>" /></figure>
  <?php
}
else{ // display a gallery of attached images within  "max" attr.
  $images=get_attached_media( 'image', (int)$atts['id'] );
  if(count($images) > 0 ){
   ?>
   <div class="gallery">
   <?php
   $index=0;
   foreach($images as $image){
     if($index < (int)$atts['max']){ //display image only if within max 
    ?>
    <figure><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID)?>" /></figure>
    <?php
      $index ++;
     }
   }
 ?></div><?php
 }     
}
return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Then in the wp editor you can use:

- [postImages id=2387  featured="true"] -> displays only featured image for post #2387
- [postImages id=2387  max = 4] -> displays a gallery of 4 images attached to post #2387

Comment: Firstly thank you for helping me out, i was struggling with this from a long time now. this is exactly what i need. one question how can i query for the image on it's full size? currently them image that i'm receiving is 150*150

Comment: try `wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( (int)$atts['id']),'medium' )[0];` OR  `wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( (int)$atts['id']),'full' )[0];`